# Auto-layout issue on scroll

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I have `.xib` which has some auto-layout like so (might need to click to zoom): 
[image]

Nothing special, I have `13pt` spacing with the border of the superview. 
This xib is then loaded in the code into a tableViewCell.

I'm also setting the height in the `viewDidLoad` of the table like so:

```
[self.tableView setEstimatedRowHeight:40];
[self.tableView setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
```

My cellForRowAtIndexPath is:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseId forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

---OR--- (Both don't make a difference)

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseId];
```

Now the fun begins. The auto-layout works when it wants to, and sometimes I scroll a cell out of view, bring it back and it's not the same size. See image below: 
[image]

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

PS: Not in the screengrab here, but I do have some cells with a lot of text that look like the same height of the big cell on left.

PPS: I've tried the following with no success (based on this article http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/08/07/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html ):

- Added `[self.tableView reloadData];` in the viewDidLoad
- I removed the explicit and preferred width on the label

Comment: are you also setting the height for this cell in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function?

Comment: I am doing this `[self.tableView setEstimatedRowHeight:40];
        [self.tableView setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];`

Comment: Could you also provide your cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @Doro Added. I tried your suggestion in the answers and it didn't work :(

Comment: @ezcoding I return  `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You have 13 points spacing not 13 pixels

Comment: @Poql Changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, it seems if you set the text of the label exclusively in `- tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` then you will observe the behaviour of random incorrectly sized cells.

I've created a test project to demonstrate this https://github.com/sja26/iOS-TestSelfSizingCellsWithUILabel

Answer (score 1):

One reason you get this behaviour - you use

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Try to use

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

instead. This will reuse your cell with the same size as needed

And, of course check `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method for properly setup value

Comment: Still jumping from big to small :(